# How to extract multiple substring matches from string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string contains tagged contents with similar patterns like below:

```
This is a <ss type="">(example)</ss> string which <ss type="">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.
```

**Expected result is:**

```
This is a <ss type="example">(example)</ss> string which <ss type="contains">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.
```

I tried to extract list of tagged contents by `RegularExpression`, and have extracted the list of tag texts, and put the tag text in the double quotes as the value of `type`, and replaced the new string with the old one.

**But the problem is**, as the `Regex.Replace();` is following the same `Regex` pattern, it replaces all tagged contents with the last element of tag contents list like below:

```
This is a <ss type="contains">(contains)</ss> string which <ss type="contains">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.
```

**My working code is below:**

```
StringBuilder resultText= new StringBuilder(@"This is a <ss type="">(example)</ss> string which <ss type="">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.");
string overallPattern = @"<ss\stype=""([a-zA-Z]*)"">(.*?)</ss>";
List<string> matchList = new List<string>();
List<string> contentList = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb;
Regex overallRegex = new Regex(overallPattern, RegexOptions.None);
string resultContent = resultText.ToString();
foreach (Match match in overallRegex.Matches(resultContent))
     {
        string matchResult = match.ToString();
        matchList.Add(matchResult);
        string content = matchResult.Split('(', ')')[1];
        contentList.Add(content);
     }
for (int j = 0; j < matchList.Count; j++)
     {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(matchList[j].Insert(10, string.Format(contentList[j])));
        resultContent = Regex.Replace(resultContent, overallPattern, sb.ToString());
        resultText = new StringBuilder();
        resultText.Append(resultContent);
     }
```

**My question is:**

> How can I put the right tag text into its double quote by order?

Comment: Have you checked your Regex pattern?As I see it's not matching anything

Comment: Ok the reason was This is a <ss type=""> which must be This is a <ss type="""">. I have already edited your question

Comment: @S.Petrosov  Thanks for your effort. It matches. Actually the string comes from somewhere else with double quote escape like `\"`. I think it is same as yours. The string above is just for demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create dynamic `Regex` based on tag content for `replace`. For example `<ss\stype="([a-zA-Z]*)">\(example\)<\/ss>` will replace only one tag having `example` in content. Please check this, it will work according to your description.

Code:

```
//StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder(@"This is a <ss type="""">(example)</ss> string which <ss type="""">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.");
//You have to use """" instead on "" in this line 
StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder(@"This is a <ss type="""">(example)</ss> string which <ss type="""">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.");
string overallPattern = @"<ss\stype=""([a-zA-Z]*)"">(.*?)</ss>";
List<string> matchList = new List<string>();
List<string> contentList = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb;
Regex overallRegex = new Regex(overallPattern, RegexOptions.None);
string resultContent = resultText.ToString();
foreach (Match match in overallRegex.Matches(resultContent))
{
    string matchResult = match.ToString();
    matchList.Add(matchResult);
    string content = matchResult.Split('(', ')')[1];
    contentList.Add(content);
}
for (int j = 0; j < matchList.Count; j++)
{
    //Dynamic Regex based on tag content for replace
    overallPattern = @"<ss\stype=""([a-zA-Z]*)"">\("+ contentList[j] + "\\)</ss>";
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(matchList[j].Insert(10, string.Format(contentList[j])));
    resultContent = Regex.Replace(resultContent, overallPattern, sb.ToString());
    resultText = new StringBuilder();
    resultText.Append(resultContent);
}
```

Output of above code:

`This is a <ss type="example">(example)</ss> string which <ss type="contains">(contains)</ss> tagged contents.`

Comment: Yay! it is working! I am not familiar with `Regex`, the dynamic part is exactly where i was confusing. Actually i was almost there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

```
resultContent = Regex.Replace(resultContent, overallPattern, sb.ToString());
```

By this:

```
resultContent = resultContent.Replace(matchList[j], sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I did this part. But what you wrote is not exactly what i was asking for.